# JavaScript ES6 Call to "super" After Async Call

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6

When using ECMAScript 6 and classes, is it possible to call the super class method from an extending class method after an async call has completed?

Here is an abstract of the question in code:

```
class Foo {
    constructor () {

    }

    myMethod (data) {
        console.log('Data was: ', data);
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    constructor () {
        super();
    }

    myMethod () {
        database.getDataForId('wth4308g40giemwfo', function (err, data) {
            super.myMethod(data);
        });
    }
}
```

Using the above class Foo.myMethod() will result in an error because super no longer refers to the superclass of Foo and is undefined inside the callback.

I have tried to keep a reference to super before the callback and use that reference in the callback after it completes but that doesn't seem to work e.g.:

```
myMethod () {
    var mySuper = super;

    database.getDataForId('wth4308g40giemwfo', function (err, data) {
        mySuper.myMethod(data);
    });
}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Just saying: A synchronous method should not be overwritten by an asynchronous one. And you should almost always take a callback or return a promise.

Comment: @Bergi True true (upvoted). This was just a contrived example to show the specific scenario rather than a best practise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Arrow functions will preserve all lexical references, not just `this`, so you can use one to access `super` too:

```
myMethod () {
    database.getDataForId('wth4308g40giemwfo', (err, data) => {
        super.myMethod(data);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot hold reference to `super` but you can to the function:

```
myMethod () {
    var myMethod = super.myMethod;
    var self = this;

    database.getDataForId('wth4308g40giemwfo', function (err, data) {
        myMethod.call(self, data);
    });
}
```

Comment: I literally just tried that out as your answer popped up and it works :) - awesome.

Comment: Apparently I have to wait 11 minutes to mark your answer as correct. Seems a bit silly when it is clearly the correct answer!

Comment: @RobEvans: Except there's a much better answer now.

Comment: @Bergi Yup that is true. I guess waiting a while does make sense then!